# After laptop lid closed keyboard not responding

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, vaio, sony

I am using **ubuntu 18.04.2 Sony Vaio**.

Keyboard is not responding after I closed the lid and tried to start the os again.

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep i8042`

```
dmesg | grep i8042

[    1.392168] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP030b:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    1.398897] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.398903] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    1.420510] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[    2.184396] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[11276.225667] i8042: Can't write CTR while closing AUX port
[11276.742411] i8042: Can't reactivate AUX port
[11277.255361] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input47
[11277.812835] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input49
[11698.821343] i8042: Can't write CTR while closing AUX port
[11699.339153] i8042: Can't reactivate AUX port
[11699.875572] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input57
[11700.423959] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input59
```

Also pasting more `dmesg` logs if required

```
[11685.592092] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: link up
[11686.150228] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[11686.155882] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[11686.744253] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 69
[11688.648727] PM: suspend exit
[11689.258022] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 70 using ehci-pci
[11689.268004] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp14s0: link is not ready
[11689.344097] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: link down
[11689.344111] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: link down
[11689.344321] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp14s0: link is not ready
[11689.345559] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp7s0: link is not ready
[11689.406864] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=0543, bcdDevice=25.11
[11689.406868] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[11689.406869] usb 1-1.3: Product: Front Camera
[11689.406871] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Generic
[11689.406873] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[11689.409150] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Front Camera (5986:0543)
[11689.416208] uvcvideo 1-1.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[11689.416211] uvcvideo 1-1.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[11689.416214] uvcvideo 1-1.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[11689.416362] input: Front Camera: Front Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input55
[11690.034661] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[11690.926189] r8169 0000:0e:00.0 enp14s0: link up
[11690.926199] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp14s0: link becomes ready
[11698.821343] i8042: Can't write CTR while closing AUX port
[11699.339153] i8042: Can't reactivate AUX port
[11699.341908] atkbd serio0: Spurious ACK on isa0060/serio0. Some program might be trying to access hardware directly.
[11699.760812] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5666], y [..4710]
[11699.788794] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1276..], y [1144..]
[11699.788810] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN2706 SYN2700 SYN0002 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[11699.841720] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126800/0x0, board id: 2739, fw id: 1366777
[11699.875572] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input57
[11700.309388] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5666], y [..4710]
[11700.337055] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1276..], y [1144..]
[11700.337071] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN2706 SYN2700 SYN0002 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[11700.390011] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126800/0x0, board id: 2739, fw id: 1366777
[11700.423959] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input59
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 5986:0543 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03eb:880f Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: I am not using the external keyboard but the inbuilt laptop keyboard

Comment: Although, I will post the result of these command

Comment: Ah I see. I misunderstood. I thought you meant that the keyboard does not work with the lid closed. Never mind...

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677850/no-keyboard-after-suspension-on-debian-testing/733398#733398

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this weird problem(My laptop is Sony Vaio too). I just pushed the button under the Vaio logo (the button is under a piece of plastic) on the back until the laptop shuts down(You can alternatively wait for the battery to drain). When it booted back it was fixed.

Comment: Force boot solves this problem but next time if you close your lid and then try to resume, you face the same problem. 

Every time force rebooting is not a solution.

Comment: i disabled suspend when laptop lid is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well, on a modern System76 Darter Pro running Pop!_OS 19.04 (based on Ubuntu). The System76 support folks have also experienced the bug. Does re-suspending and re-resuming help?

Upon resume, I get in my dmesg:

```
i8042: failed to resume active multiplexor, mouse won't work
```

Re-suspending the laptop and then resuming again fixes the problem for me. It only appears to affect me when I have the linux-lowlatency kernel running (with rtirq enabled). I have no been able to reproduce yet (to my knowledge/memory) on linux-generic.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from this problem as well, but [this script](https://github.com/mistine/i8042-keyboard-fix-linux) seems to fix it.