# Laptop Ubuntu 20.04: integrated keyboard does not function after closing the lid, touchscreen and mousepad works

Tags: keyboard, suspend, power-management, laptop, touchscreen

### Background

In earlier versions of Ubuntu, there were similar issues, as asked in [question 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096448/keyboard-dead-after-lid-close-lid-open-18-10-detachable-laptop) and [question 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146812/after-laptop-lid-closed-keyboard-not-responding).

### Details of the situation

With suspend when lid closed setting as ON,

- when the lid is closed, it sleeps as expected
- when the lid is opened, it wakes the laptop up. However, the integrated keyboard doesn't function, whereas, the touchscreen and the touchpad of the laptop continue to function.

This issue was not observed in Ubuntu 18.04.x.

### Question

How to resolve this issue.

Kindly note that the situation in this question differs from the existing ones as the laptop's integrated keyboard is freezing following suspension and touchscreen and touchpad remain functional.

Please let me know what terminal command outputs I should include in this question to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224316...
It worked for me on 20.04...

I added `i8042.direct` instead of `i8042.dumbkbd` to the end of the boot command in the boot menu to check if this works...
Then I permanently added it to the booting command.

If you, like me, are not using grub, but rather systemd, you should edit a file called something like

```
/boot/efi/loader/entries/whatever-name-does-it-have.conf
```

adding.